# Swift: Realm array empty after writing object

Tags: swift, realm

First of all, i'm new to Swift, so probably I have made some stupid mistake, but I have tried everything and I can't figure it out why this is happening.

So let me start. List property inside realm object is not being stored. That is first problem and second problem is that object I'm calling after adding object to realm loses it property value.

Here is the picture, so you guys can understand better what I'm saying

[image]

And now this is output:

```
PRODUCT BEFORE UPDATE: 34
Added new object
PRODUCT AFTER UPDATE:
```

I will show how my `DBManager` class looks:

```
    import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class DBManager {
    private var   database:Realm
    static let   sharedInstance = DBManager()
    private init() {
        database = try! Realm()
}

func getDataFromDB() ->   Results<Product> {
    let results: Results<Product> = database.objects(Product.self)
    return results
}

func getSingleDataFromDB(primaryKey: String) -> Product {
    let product: Product = database.object(ofType: Product.self, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey)!
    return product
}

func addData(object: Product)   {
    try! database.write {
        database.add(object)
        print("Added new object")
    }
}

func updateData(object: Product) {
    try! database.write {
        database.add(object, update: true)  
    }
}

func deleteAllFromDatabase()  {
    try!   database.write {
        database.deleteAll()
    }
}

func deleteFromDb(object: Product)   {
    try!   database.write {
        database.delete(object)
    }
}
}
```

So If someone is seeing something that I'm not seeing, please let me know because I have lost many hours finding solution for this problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you find a reason?